# Let $\alpha > 0$, $M_t=\exp(\alpha B_t - \alpha^2 t/2)$ for all $t \ge 0$. Show that $M_t \to 0$ a.s.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $\alpha > 0$, $M_t=\exp(\alpha B_t - \alpha^2 t/2)$ for all $t \ge 0$. Show that $M_t \to 0$ a.s.

I have started a class in stochastic Calculus and we are using the text by Steele. I have been staring at this text book for days and I just can't seem to understand this. I guess I don't have sufficient background in probability theory. Apparently we are supposed to use the inversion property of Brownian motion for the main tool here but I still cannot see it. I know that what we are trying to show is this.
$$P \left ( \lim_{t \to \infty} M_t = 0 \right) = 1$$

We have a main tool called Doob's Maximal inequality which is supposed to be used for probabilistic purposes but I'm not sure if it fits in. I start by trying to take a limit.

$$\lim_{t \to \infty }\exp(\alpha B_t - \alpha^2 t/2) = \lim_{t \to \infty } \frac{ \exp(\alpha B_t) }{ \exp(\alpha^2 t/2) }$$

I know the point is that we need to show somehow that the denominator increased "faster" than the numerator, so this limit goes to zero. However I really am at a loss for how to proceed. I don't see how to fit probability into it. I feel that I have had zero examples about how this works I just don't understand the technique.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use Martingale ConvergenceTheorem.

Comment: You do know that you are dealing with a martingale, right? We have a result for martingales that allows these kind of results, it is called the Martingale convergence theorem. Can you attempt to apply it?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes, sorry I didn't write that.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241149/convergence-of-exponential-brownian-martingale-to-zero-almost-surely

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence of exponential Brownian martingale to zero almost surely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241149/convergence-of-exponential-brownian-martingale-to-zero-almost-surely)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy This is my main issue with this class. The prof says, use this thm or that thm. OK so I have the Martingale Convergence Theorem that says $M_t \to M_\infty$ a.s, but that point is that I don't know that $M_\infty = 0$, that is what I'm trying to show. So this doesn't help me.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind Is the attached answer helpful to you? See , to "understand" what $M_{\infty}$ could be, you need to look at the "long-term" behaviour of the martingale itself. The attached answer uses time-inversion to actually convert the problem of looking at "long-term" behaviour, to looking at the process "near zero" where things are easier to analyse. Then the rest is pretty clear (to me : I can understand if you are confused, please ask if you have any issues). I can see you are having issues integrating class material into problems : you can speak more about this to me.

Comment: Thank you @TeresaLisbon I am going through that answer. I can see that using the inversion is a neat trick. Of course it isn't so intuitive since $M_t$ is a martingale $E[M_t]=E[M_0]=1$. But I need to stare at it for a few minutes I will get back to you.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind Sure, please take your time.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon ok yes as long as I accept the properties of the inverted Brownian motion then yes the rest of the math I agree with. However in this case it seems that all we have proven is that $P( \lim_{t \to \infty} \alpha B_t - \alpha^2 t/2 = -\infty ) = 1$. It seems we still need an additional property to bring the exponential function inside the limit. This may be a common property of probability theory but I am not familiar. (Thanks so much for your comments)

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind It's called an "$\omega$-by-$\omega$" argument : basically, the set of $\omega$ in the sample space such that $\alpha B_t(\omega) - \alpha \frac{t^2}2 \to -\infty$ has prob. $1$. For each such $\omega$, we can take the exponential and use a property of the exponential to see that $e^{\alpha B_t(\omega) - \alpha \frac{t^2}2} \to e^{-\infty} = 0$ for each such $\omega$ in that set, and therefore with prob. $1$ as well. This basically says : look at each element of the sample space and imagine that it occurred. Then work from there.

Comment: The "$\omega$-by-$\omega$" argument works very well in providing *intuition* for problems regarding stochastic processes, as you can see from this example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119493/discussion-between-jeffery-the-wind-and-teresa-lisbon).